# How to update selected row from List when receving value from publisher in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `List()` that I want to update item's text when `contextMenu` button is tapped.

When the button is tapped a `@Published` value is updated. I listen to value changes with `onReceive` and if that value is true the list item where I long pressed to bring the `contextMenu` and tap the button should update its text.

The issue is that all the items from the list are updated. So `onReceive` is hit for every element from the list. In one way I understand because elements are populated in `ForEach` although my expectation was to update only one item.

The behaviour I'm trying to replicate is from Notes app when you long press a Note and tap `Lock Note`. On that action the lock is applied only for the selected Note.

I tried to capture the selected index but again the `onReceive` is triggered for every item from the list.

How to define a custom modifier like `onDelete` that deletes at the right `IndexSet` or a function that can take the `IndexSet` and apply the changes I need to that index?

Here is the code I'm trying to solve.

```
import SwiftUI

class MyPublish: ObservableObject {
    @Published var publish = false
}

struct Ocean: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
    var hasPhoto: Bool = false
}

struct OceanDetails: View {
    var ocean: Ocean

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(ocean.name)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myPublish: MyPublish

    @State private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List() {
                ForEach(Array(oceans.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index,ocean) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: OceanDetails(ocean: ocean)) {
                        ocean.hasPhoto ? Text(ocean.name) + Text(Image(systemName: "photo")) : Text("\(ocean.name)")
                    }
                    .contextMenu() {
                        Button("Publish") {
                            myPublish.publish.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(myPublish.$publish) { publish in
                        if publish {
                            oceans[index].hasPhoto.toggle()
                            myPublish.publish = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }
        }
    }

    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            oceans.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(MyPublish())
    }
}
```

This is just a replication from my app. I want to understand how this `onReceive` is working or if it is a good idea to apply it on `ForEach`. I tried to move it on `List()` level but I don't have access anymore to index that I get from the loop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You way overcomplicated things. A much simpler approach will get you a great deal further. I have included what has been changed, if it isn't here, it us unchanged.

First, there is no reason to have the ViewModel simply be a publisher for a toggle. Since you had a `ViewModel` I used it, but this could be done more simply in the view by simply adding the `selectedOcean` variable:

```
class MyPublish: ObservableObject {
    @Published var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]
    // Keep track of the selected ocean.
    @Published var selectedOcean: Ocean?
}
```

I conformed the struct to equatable so I could use ==

```
struct Ocean: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
    var hasPhoto: Bool = false
}
```

See the comments in the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myPublish: MyPublish
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List { // List doesn't need the ()
                // since oceans is Identifiable, you can access it simply like this
                ForEach(myPublish.oceans) { ocean in
                    NavigationLink(destination: OceanDetails(ocean: ocean)) {
                        ocean.hasPhoto ? Text(ocean.name) + Text(Image(systemName: "photo")) : Text("\(ocean.name)")
                    }
                    .contextMenu() {
                        Button("Publish") {
                            // set the selected ocean to the ocean from the appropriate row. This will also trigger
                            // The publisher to fire with the change.
                            myPublish.selectedOcean = ocean
                        }
                    }
                    // The publisher is received here
                    .onReceive(myPublish.$selectedOcean) { selectedOcean in
                        if let selectedOcean, // unwrap it. If it is nil, we skip the function.
                           // get the index of the selected ocean in the array.
                           let index = myPublish.oceans.firstIndex(where: { ocean in
                            ocean == selectedOcean
                        }) {
                            // Use the index to toggle the setting
                                myPublish.oceans[index].hasPhoto.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                }
                // because you are not using the enumberation, removeRows just works.
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            myPublish.oceans.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `MyPublish` is actually a biometrics handler where the value of `publish` is set true if face id match. So it kind of has to be alone, I mean I cannot include `@Published var selectedOcean: Ocean?` in it. And the array of oceans in the real app is stored in `CoreData`. So I have to get the result of biometric authentication in `onReceive` and then update the text on the selected item from the list. Pretty sure it can be done but not sure how to work with `onReceive` to capture only the selected item. I see in in Notes app, that behaviour I want to replicate. Thanks!

Comment: You need to ask a new question with an actual Minimal Reproducible Example. The fact of the data being persisted in `CoreData` would make no difference. `CoreData` classes conform to `Observable`. Same with the fact that you are using the `LocalAuthentication` APIs. They are a gate before you pass you selection. Otherwise, you are radically increasing the complexity because your original code is difficult to reason.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to answer my question. I have asked another question with Minimal Reproducible Example which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682837/how-to-update-selected-row-from-list-after-face-id-matched-in-swiftui