# How to update selected row from List after Face ID matched in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, face-id

I have a `List` that I want to update item's text when `contextMenu` button is tapped.

When the button is tapped a `@Published` value is updated. I listen to value changes with `onReceive` and if that value is true the list item where I long pressed to bring the `contextMenu` and tap the button should update its text.

The issue is that all the items from the list are updated. So `onReceive` is hit for every element from the list. In one way I understand because elements are populated in `ForEach` although my expectation was to update only one item.

The behaviour I'm trying to replicate is from Notes app when you long press a Note and tap `Lock Note`. On that action the lock is applied only for the selected Note.

I tried to capture the selected index but again the `onReceive` is triggered for every item from the list.

How to define a custom modifier like `onDelete` that deletes at the right `IndexSet` or a function that can take the `IndexSet` and apply the changes I need to that index?

Here is the code I'm trying to solve.

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

enum BiometricStates {
    case available
    case lockedOut
    case notAvailable
    case unknown
}

class BiometricsHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var biometricsAvailable = false
    @Published var isUnlocked = false

    private var context = LAContext()

    private var biometryState = BiometricStates.unknown {
        didSet {
            switch biometryState {
            case .available:
                self.biometricsAvailable = true
            case .lockedOut:
//                self.loginState = .biometryLockout
                self.biometricsAvailable = false
            case .notAvailable, .unknown:
                self.biometricsAvailable = false
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
//        self.loginState = .loggedOut
        checkBiometrics()
    }

    private func checkBiometrics() {
        var evaluationError: NSError?
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &evaluationError) {
            switch context.biometryType {
            case .faceID, .touchID:
                biometryState = .available
            default:
                biometryState = .unknown
            }
        } else {
            guard let error = evaluationError else {
                biometryState = .unknown
                return
            }
        
            let errorCode = LAError(_nsError: error).code
        
            switch(errorCode) {
            case .biometryNotEnrolled, .biometryNotAvailable:
                biometryState = .notAvailable
            case .biometryLockout:
                biometryState = .lockedOut
            default:
                biometryState = .unknown
            }
        }
    }

    func authenticate() {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
    
        // check wether biometric authentication is possible
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            // it's possible, so go ahead and use it
            let reason = "We need to unlock your data"
        
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                // authentication has now completed
                if success {
                    // authenticated successfully
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        self.isUnlocked = true
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // there was a problem
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // no biometrics
        }
    }
}

struct Ocean: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
    var hasPhoto: Bool = false
}

struct OceanDetails: View {
    var ocean: Ocean

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(ocean.name)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var biometricsHandler: BiometricsHandler

    @State private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(oceans.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index,ocean) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: OceanDetails(ocean: ocean)) {
                        ocean.hasPhoto ? Text(ocean.name) + Text(Image(systemName: "lock")) : Text("\(ocean.name)")
                    }
                    .contextMenu() {
                        Button(action: {
                            biometricsHandler.authenticate()
                        }) {
                            if ocean.hasPhoto {
                                Label("Remove lock", systemImage: "lock.slash")
                            } else {
                                Label("Lock", systemImage: "lock")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onReceive(biometricsHandler.$isUnlocked) { isUnlocked in
                        if isUnlocked {
                            oceans[index].hasPhoto.toggle()
                            biometricsHandler.isUnlocked = false
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }
        }
    }

    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            oceans.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(BiometricsHandler())
    }
}
```

This is just a replication from my app. I want to understand how this `onReceive` is working or if it is a good idea to apply it on `ForEach`. I tried to move it on `List` level but I don't have access anymore to index that I get from the loop.

Also would like to mention that in real app the data is being persisted in `CoreData` but for simplicity I created an array in this exmple.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you alread asked this question, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76674911/how-to-update-selected-row-from-list-when-receving-value-from-publisher-in-swift

Comment: That doesn’t answer this question. I’ve been asked to post a different question so here I am. That question will be closed/deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. I moved `onReceive` on `List` level and got the selected item from the list, the one that is tapped for the context menu to show. Set the selected item after the call to authenticate.

```
import SwiftUI
import LocalAuthentication

enum BiometricStates {
    case available
    case lockedOut
    case notAvailable
    case unknown
}

class BiometricsHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var biometricsAvailable = false
    @Published var isUnlocked = false

    private var context = LAContext()

    private var biometryState = BiometricStates.unknown {
        didSet {
            switch biometryState {
            case .available:
                self.biometricsAvailable = true
            case .lockedOut:
//                self.loginState = .biometryLockout
                self.biometricsAvailable = false
            case .notAvailable, .unknown:
                self.biometricsAvailable = false
            }
        }
    }

    init() {
//        self.loginState = .loggedOut
        checkBiometrics()
    }

    private func checkBiometrics() {
        var evaluationError: NSError?
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &evaluationError) {
            switch context.biometryType {
            case .faceID, .touchID:
                biometryState = .available
            default:
                biometryState = .unknown
            }
        } else {
            guard let error = evaluationError else {
                biometryState = .unknown
                return
            }
        
            let errorCode = LAError(_nsError: error).code
        
            switch(errorCode) {
            case .biometryNotEnrolled, .biometryNotAvailable:
                biometryState = .notAvailable
            case .biometryLockout:
                biometryState = .lockedOut
            default:
                biometryState = .unknown
            }
        }
    }

    func authenticate() {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
    
        // check wether biometric authentication is possible
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            // it's possible, so go ahead and use it
            let reason = "We need to unlock your data"
        
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                // authentication has now completed
                if success {
                    // authenticated successfully
                    Task { @MainActor in
                        self.isUnlocked = true
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // there was a problem
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // no biometrics
        }
    }

    func passcodeAuthenticate() {
        let context = LAContext()
        var error: NSError?
    
        // check wether biometric authentication is possible
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
            // it's possible, so go ahead and use it
            let reason = "Authenticate to access your data"
        
            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
                // authentication has now completed
                if success {
                    // authenticated successfully
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.isUnlocked = true
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // there was a problem
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            // no biometrics
        }

    }
}

struct Ocean: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let name: String
    let id = UUID()
    var hasPhoto: Bool = false
}

struct OceanDetails: View {
    var ocean: Ocean

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(ocean.name)")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var biometricsHandler: BiometricsHandler

    @State private var oceans = [
        Ocean(name: "Pacific"),
        Ocean(name: "Atlantic"),
        Ocean(name: "Indian"),
        Ocean(name: "Southern"),
        Ocean(name: "Arctic")
    ]
    @State var selectedOcean: Ocean?
    @State var selectedIndex: Int?
    @State var biometricsCalls: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Array(oceans.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index,ocean) in
                    NavigationLink(destination: OceanDetails(ocean: ocean)) {
                        ocean.hasPhoto ? Text(ocean.name) + Text(Image(systemName: "lock")) : Text("\(ocean.name)")
                    }
                    .contextMenu() {
                        Button(action: {
                            biometricsHandler.authenticate()
                            if biometricsHandler.isUnlocked {
                                biometricsHandler.passcodeAuthenticate()
                            }
                            selectedOcean = ocean
                        }) {
                            if ocean.hasPhoto {
                                Label("Remove lock", systemImage: "lock.slash")
                            } else {
                                Label("Lock", systemImage: "lock")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeRows)
            }
            .onReceive(biometricsHandler.$isUnlocked) { isUnlocked in
                if isUnlocked {
                    if let index = oceans.firstIndex(where: {$0 == selectedOcean}) {
                        oceans[index].hasPhoto.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            oceans.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(BiometricsHandler())
    }
}
```